# add array in mysql from eloquent fillable laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to add array in my mysql database, for which i create a controller in which i accept array from postman and send data from postman by adding '[]' to phone_no.
my controller:

```
$rules=[
            'name' => 'required',
            'password'  => 'required',
            'phone_no'=>'required', 
 ];

        $validator=Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,[
            'phone_no.*'=>'required',
        ]
    );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(),400);
        }
        $user=Model::create($request->all());
```

my model:

```
protected $fillable =[
            'name',
            'password',
            'phone_no',
 ];
```

but it add nothing in my database, other attributes added but my phone_no  column is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can't store an array in mysql database. you can serialize it or convert it to a json. My suggestion is using "Array and JSON Casting" like this:

```
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting
```

Add this to your model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'phone_no' => 'array',
];
```